# aria-labelledby attribute not reading when pressing tab and navigation key(right/left arrows)

Tags: angular, wai-aria, nvda

I am new to aria accessibilities. When I am pressing tab or left/right arrow screen reader NVDA reading as clickable but when I am mouse over it was reading properly. I am using angular 7

Template:

> <span role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-labelledby="chart-close"
> id="close_svg" style="width: 25px; height: 31px; margin-top: -6%;
> padding-right: 4px; fill: #ffffff;  stroke: #ffffff; stroke-width:
> 0.1rem; display: inline-block;" tabindex="0"  (click)="closeChat()" placement="bottom" [ngbTooltip]="CloseChat"
> ng-reflect-inline-s-v-g="/assets/icons/chat-close.svg">
>
>
>
>
> <ng-template #CloseChat tabindex="-1">
> Close Chat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an element has a click() handler or one of the element's ancestors has a click() handler, then NVDA will say "clickable" if the element is not a natively interactive element.  In your case, a `<span>` is not a natively interactive element **and** it has a click() handler, so you're going to hear "clickable".  It's a way for the screen reader to tell the user they can select the element even though it's not normally a clickable thing.

Most screen reader users aren't mouse users so you don't have to worry about **not** hearing clickable when you hover with the mouse.  Most NVDA users turn off mouse tracking anyway so that the screen reader isn't so chatty when moving the mouse over elements.